# How to create index of an instance method in elasticsearch-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

**What I want to do**

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model

Using this gem, I wanna create indexes of User model, including output of method named `full_name`. `User` has columns of `id, first_name, last_name`.

```
class User
  ...
  def full_name
    first_name + last_name
  end
  ...
end
```

**What I did**

```
module UserSearchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Searchable
    settings index: {
      ...
    }

    mappings do
      indexes :id, type: :integer
      indexes :first_name, type: text
      indexes :last_name, type: text
      indexes :full_name, type: text, as: 'full_name'
    end

    def as_indexed_json(options={})
      as_json(
        methods: [:full_name]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

I referred to this question.
[Index the results of a method in ElasticSearch (Tire + ActiveRecord)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600086/index-the-results-of-a-method-in-elasticsearch-tire-activerecord)

But this doesn't work, ending up with not containing `full_name` index in the response.

I'm new to elasticsearch and elasticsearch-rails.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you remember to include it in your model user.rb?  You need `include UserSearchable` at the top of class definition.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Of course, I include it ! I can index first_name and last_name correctly!

Comment: did you try adding `methods: [:country_ja, :full_name], ` take a look at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model#relationships-and-associations

Comment: You can also do this by using Elasticsearch mapping, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html

Comment: Sorry :country_ja was typo of :full_name. fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just forgot to reload changes in the code!
And It works without `as: 'full_name'` in current version of the gem.