# Elasticsearch, Tire, and Nested fields with ActiveRecord

Tags: activerecord, elasticsearch, tire

Please read this answer to a similar question I have below [Elasticsearch, Tire, and Nested queries / associations with ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692560/elasticsearch-tire-and-nested-queries-associations-with-activerecord)

Lets say I added the following field the the Book model provided in the question above:

`field :account_tags, type: Array # [{:account_id => 1, :tags => ["tag1", "tag2"], :acccount_id => 2, :tags => ["tag3", "tag4"] }]`

I now would like to set up an index to seach these account_ids or tags.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem and was straight forward.  My mapping looks like

```
mapping do 
  ...  
  indexes :account_tags do
    indexes :account_id, :index => "not_analyzed"
    indexes :tags, :type => 'string', :analyzer => 'keyword'
  end
end
```

My to_indexed_json looks like

```
def to_indexed_json
  {
    ...
    account_tags: account_tags
  }.to_json
end
```

Now I can search via

```
@query = "account_id:#{account_id}"
@tags = tags

Book.tire.search :load => true do |search|
  search.query do |query|
    query.string @query
  end

  search.filter :terms, :tags => @tags
end
```

This is a bare boned solution that I used to prototype a system.