# Elastic Search and Tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, tire

Hello I am trying to use tire and elasticsearch in my project.

I am able to index the models and query each of them, but i have difficulty with join tables.

My Model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :name, :rating
belongs_to :category
has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks
after_save do
  update_index
end

tire.mapping do
  indexes :name,  :analyzer => 'snowball', :boost => 100
  indexes :posts
end
end



class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
has_and_belongs_to_many :items


attr_accessible :posted_at, :text, :thread_id, :username

tire.mapping do
  indexes :id, type: 'integer'
  indexes :text, :analyzer => 'snowball', :boost => 100
  indexes :thread_id, type: 'integer'
  indexes :posted_at, type: 'date'
end
end
```

As you can see i Have a join table between Item and Post

If i have an Item Name how can i search for Post.search(those posts that belong to this item) with elastic search or Item.search(name).posts?

Comment: i think that tire is not flexible enough to do that. it would need to search in two different document types. i think that you will have to write your own query using the tire query dsl.

Answer (score 1):

probably the best you can do is to start here :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692560/elasticsearch-tire-and-nested-queries-associations-with-activerecord/11711477#11711477
```

and then watch `http://railscasts.com/episodes/307-elasticsearch-part-2`

and then just browse tire from top down `http://karmi.github.io/retire/`

I am solving something similar... will let you know how I solve the thing :)

Comment: Thank you Redrick. Will try your suggestion and will wait to see if you come up with a solution.Meanwhile i will try too.

Comment: hi there, I solved my problems with elasticsearch, if you want, I got some code + blog post on http://blog.antasandrej.net (wait for it to load its hosted on heroku, it sleeps a lot :) ), there you find the github links, if you are still unable to use the think, just try to contact me, I got myself a pretty damn complicated setup, so I am sure I can help you too now :) have a nice day